# Android studio, не могу наследоваться

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Что-то случилось и сейчас не могу наследоваться не от одного класса загорается красным.
Что делать?

Comment: А что говорит Android Studio по поводу возникшей ситуации? Why?

Comment: Resolve cannot symble и предлогает импортироать сдк

Comment: У вас что-то отвалилось. Из-за того, что никой инфы вы больше не предоставили нельзя посоветовать ничего кроме перезагрузки и переустановки всего, чего только можно.

Comment: а сам андроид мне ниче не предостаил как быть что попробоать :?

Comment: Проверьте в настройках студии и проекта все пути до явы и СДК

Comment: Сделал апдпейт плагина щас классы пояились но cannot resolve symbol bundle

Comment: пипец может   сдк перезалить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь никто не сталкнеться с этим Опишу 2 метода

!1 обновляете свой добавив + к концу вашей версии `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0+"`

!2 метод `Файл-> Invalidate кэшей / Restart`

Очистка / восстановление проекта
Утратившими силу кэши и перезапуск